# Send a value automatically to the client using WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a service that provides data to a WPF application , and one of these data is a value called Market Price that i want it to be updated every minute for example( i am just doing a simulation, so the service will return a random value). So i want to know the best and simplest way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer) class.
Declare this on the constructor class and set the interval as you need:

```
var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);//method to be executed
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);//the interval is set to 1 second
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

And declare a method to be executed:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call WCF service and update the value
}
```

Comment: humm,  I will try it now, Thank you